# Regression on leptokurtotic data

Tags: regression, kurtosis, truncation

I'd like to model some data with high kurtosis, with the goal of predicting the response variable outside some threshold in the tails especially.

OLS seems to do a bad job of this as the residuals become large at the extremes. There seems to be a few classes in literature of how to deal with data exhibiting high kurtosis, most of it seems to involve power transformations of the response variable or using a robust regression model. These generally suppress the effect of the 'outliers', which is not what I want, since my end use case is to predict the response variable far out in its conditional distribution.

What's a good approach for tackling this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quantile regression would be one, robust approach. There are any number of transformations that would make your dependent variable and the associated residuals more tractable. These include Lambert's W, the inverse hyperbolic sine transformation and the Box-Cox. The problems with all of these transformations, when applied to the DV, is, 1) challenges with transforming the values of any predictions back into the original metric (if that's needed) and, 2) even if you can get the predictions back into some semblance of the original metric, there is still likely to be substantial retransformation bias.